# How do I change text data to numeric in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    a.AccountNumber, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Address, a.City, a.State, 
    a.Zip, a.EmailAddress, a.PhoneNumber, a.LastUpdated, a.LastVisit, 
    a.TotalSales, a.AccountOpened, a.CustomText4 as StoreCode, 
    CASE
        WHEN (a.CustomText1 IS 'JAN') THEN '1' 
    END AS DOB, 
    GETDATE() as Extract_date
FROM 
    database.dbo.Customer a
```

`CustomText1` column has Month data with a text data.I am trying to convert JAN-DEC to Numeric.

`CASE WHEN IS '' isn't working.`

Comment: Please try this `WHEN (a.CustomText1 LIKE 'JAN%') THEN '1' `

Comment: Case a.CustomText when 'Jan' then 1 when 'Feb' then 2....

Comment: The problem is that you are using IS in there instead of =.

Answer (score 7):

"IS" is not a valid expression for CASE statement.  Check the [online doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), you have a couple ways to do it, this is the simplest way, repeat for the rest of the months.

```
SELECT DOB = 
    CASE a.CustomText1
        WHEN 'JAN' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'FEB' THEN '2'
        WHEN 'MAR' THEN '3'
        ELSE a.CustomText1
    END
FROM database.dbo.Customer a
```

Answer (score 1):

Greg's answer works, but it's over 12 lines. Here's how to do it in one.

```
SELECT MONTH(CAST('01' + CustomText1 + '00' AS DATE))
FROM dbo.Customer
```

Comment: Yes, that is definitely more optimal, but since the column name is "CustomText1", you have to anticipate or guard against unexpected values.  The function would raise an error for any other invalid string, at least CASE has the ELSE condition to guard against that.